# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.....' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-studio, google-api, dependencies

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I read some suggestion i try all of them but still i can not the problem.Plz help

Here dependencies ->

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
compile files('libs/Parse-1.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/Parse-1.6.0.jar')
```

}

Comment: Why do you reference Parse.jar twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. remove one Parse.jar (Android studio does not know which version to prefer)
2. `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'`

instead of

`compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')`

as google services contain res files, therefore they cannot be imported only through a .jar

3. remove `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` as you dont want to compile all, what is in libs.